# Passing artifact name for Vlocity deployment validations

Tags: salesforcedx, github, cicd, vlocity, github-actions

This is for Vlocity deployment using Github Actions.

Scenario: In the code repo I have made a minor change in my Omniscript and I want to validate this change before I deploy.

Following is the yml file which triggers when a pull request is created for Dev_Sanbox1.
I have created an artifact using SF power script and saved it.
On the very last line, I need to validate the velocity deployment.

**How can I use the saved artifact to validate my deployment?**

**How to pass the artifact name in this command?**

**Is there any other recommended way I can deploy using my artifact?**

```
    name: HandlePullRequest

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: Dev_Sandbox1
  
jobs:
  authenticate-deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            # Checkout the source code
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
              
            # Install Salesforce CLI
            - name: 'Install Salesforce CLI'
              run: |
                  wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
                  mkdir sfdx-cli
                  tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx-cli --strip-components 1
                  ./sfdx-cli/install
                  echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install sfpowerkit
            
            # Authenticate dev hub
            - name: 'Authenticate Dev Hub'
              run: |
                sfdx sfpowerkit:auth:login -u ${{ secrets.USER_NAME}} -p ${{ secrets.USER_PASSWORD}} -r ${{ secrets.TARGET_URL}}

            # Delta deployment validation
            - name: 'Delta deployment validation'
              run: |
                git remote set-url origin https://github.com/abcEnergy/SalesforcePOC.git    
                git fetch
                git checkout $GITHUB_HEAD_REF
                git pull
                SOURCE_COMMIT_ID=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
                echo $SOURCE_COMMIT_ID
                git checkout $GITHUB_BASE_REF
                git pull
                TARGET_COMMIT_ID=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)
                echo $TARGET_COMMIT_ID
                sfdx sfpowerkit:project:diff -r $TARGET_COMMIT_ID -t $SOURCE_COMMIT_ID -d Delta_pkg_${{github.run_number}} 

            # Save the delta as an artifact
            - name: Store Delta changes
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
              with:
                name: Delta_changes
                path: |
                  ${{ github.workspace }}/Delta_pkg_${{github.run_number}}/**    

            #Downloading the artifact
            - name: Get Delta changes
              uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
              with:
                name: Delta_changes

            # Validating and deploying the deployment
            - name: 'Validation and deployment'
              run: |
                sfdx force:source:deploy -c -u fname.lname@abcenergy.com.dptest1 -x buildfiles/deploy_to_qa.yaml -w 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to re-download the artifact (which, here, is just a directory full of metadata). It's right there on the file system of your Actions runner, at `Delta_pkg_${{github.run_number}}`.

Just give that path to `sfdx force:source:deploy -c`.